# Help with youtube embed!

Tags: youtube, embed

Help! Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to produce a clickable image link so that when clicked it will start my youtube video. Here's what I have...

```
<iframe class="youtube" width="400" height="257" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/I-TiwjSELQE?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen imgsrc="images/ciafree-yt" width="413" height="242"></iframe>
```

Thank you : )

Comment: Lol, "Here's what I have..." *shows nothing*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery and simply add `id="yt-video"` to your embed code.

Make sure you reference jQuery (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js`) in your HTML as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Then add this simple jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yt-video').hide(); // hides the video initially
    $('#id_of_image_div_clicked').click(function(){
       $('#id_of_image_div_clicked').hide(); // hides the clicked image
       $('#yt-video').show(); // shows the video
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit of a novice, sorry...but how could I add an id to the video that's already in the iframe class?

Comment: Just add `<iframe id="yt-video"  [rest of the iframe code goes here]  >`

Answer (score 0):

If don't matters for you try to use `<object>` tags like I'm using